# Python: preventing Tkinter buttons from having an "animation"

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

While writing a simple interactive tic tac toe program in Python, using Tkinter to make a GUI, I faced a problem when coding a button.

Whenever you press a button in a Tkinter-based GUI, the button has this "animation" where as long as it's pressed in, it "jumps" slightly downwards and to the right - and when it's released, it jumps back to its original form. I was wondering whether it's possible to prevent this animation from taking place, but still have the button execute a command while being pressed (in other words: function as a button, but look like a plain image).

If it's worth anything, my relevant code is as follows:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tkinter.Tk()
button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(<path>))
button = tkinter.Button(window, image=button_image, borderwidth=0)
button.grid(row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably don't want a Button at all; put your image on a Label, and use `.bind()` to handle mouse clicks on it.  Note that this is a horrible idea from a UI design point of view, as you're taking away all feedback that the image actually responded to the click.

Comment: @jasonharper I understand, but the point is for somebody to be able to click on one of the squares of the tic tac toe table, and for there to appear a naught/cross. The whole idea is for them not to know that there's in fact a button/label there; to them it just looks like they're pressing on an empty space and a naught/cross appears. When it comes to using a label however: I will try that, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of a button a label?

```
panel = Label(root, image=button_image)
panel.image = button_image
panel.grid(row=1)
```

Comment: Your answer would be a bit better if it also included information about how to call a function when the label is clicked.

Comment: oof, I don't think that that's possible. I think that if you want a image on a button you may go to Visual Studio C# forms, python tkinter is a little limited.

Comment: It's definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new answer, what if you do this?

```
button_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(<path>))
for _ in range(5):
    button = tkinter.button(root, image=button_image, borderwidth=0, relief=SUNKEN)
    button.grid(row=1)
root.mainloop()
```